# Shell Script to login into a website

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

I want to login into a website using a shell script and at the same time I want to automatically take the user id and the password also.

Please suggest how is it done using shell script.

Thanks !!!

Comment: What, precisely, are you trying to accomplish? (TLDR: Why?)

Comment: I want my script to open a webpage and enter my user name and password from the script

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If what you want to do is retrieve content from a website using HTTP Basic authentication then you can achieve this from the command line using wget or curl:

```
wget --http-user=user --http-password=password 

curl http://username:password@website.com/url
```

If cookie-based authentication is used you may be able to use wget for this too, depending on how it is set up. If for example you can HTTP POST to the login page

```
wget --save-cookies cookies.txt --post-data \
'user=myusername&password=mypassword' http://url/loginpage

wget --load-cookies cookies.txt -p http://url/thecontentIwant
```

The --save-cookies and --load-cookies allow for cookie-based authentication tokens to persist between requests.

If the form of authentication being used is more complex then the answer is going to be quite different - so it would help to state which website you have in mind. Furthermore, many sites have APIs that you should use instead...

In general it would help if you could clarify the question a little -- I find this bit 'at the same time I want to automatically take the user id and the password also' a bit confusing. If you want to do an interactive session in bash (i.e. getting the user to input username and password into the bash script) then you will find

```
read -e -p
```

very useful (eg.  read -e -p "My prompt: " varname; echo $varname).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how the website is set up.  If it's using basic HTTP authentication you may be able to use wget or curl and supply the username and password via command line arguments.  If the login info is submitted via a form you can append it to the URL or add it to the post data.

If the login is something more esoteric you m,ay have to script a browser session with something like Selenium.  It depends entirely on how the website's authentication system.